# Sliding div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hy guys! I have to make a sliding div (left-right) using jquery. This is a link to what I have at this moment: http://www.k-prim.biz/test/test.html
This works fine but I do not know how to make the div to slides left on clicking the arrow image after it is already moved to right. Any help?

Thanks

Comment: would you consider to use CSS3 animation or do you need to make it work also on IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply try this code instead of your script side.

```
  $(function(){
       var i = 0;
       $("#clicky").click(function(){
       if(i==0){
           i =1;
           $("#slide").animate({marginLeft:'500px'},'slow', function(){
                 $("img#clicky").attr("src", "right.jpg");
            });
       }else{
          i=0;
          $("#slide").animate({marginLeft:'0px'},'slow', function(){
             $("img#clicky").attr("src", "left.jpg");
          });
        }
   });
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Alternative could be  a css-approach, using css transitions. [See jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/5Ld7d/).

The click handle in that case is as simple as (**edit** click handler on `div#slide`, because the arrow image is now its background, jsfiddle is adjusted accordingly):

```
$("#slide").click(function(){
    var el= $(this)
       ,isRight = /right/i.test(el.attr('class'))
       ,addremove = isRight ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass';
    el[addremove]('right');
 });​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var pos=0;
$(function(){
    $("#clicky").click(function(){
                if(pos==0)
                {
                    $("#slide").animate({marginLeft:'500px'},'slow', function(){
                              $("img#clicky").attr("src", "right.jpg");
                    }); 
                    pos = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#slide").animate({marginLeft:'0px'},'slow', function(){
                              $("img#clicky").attr("src", "left.jpg");
                    });  
                    pos = 0;
                }
    });            
});
</script>
```

This may help you in thinking on an algorithm.

**Notice :** Not tested code, edited.

Comment: you should also update the value of `pos` or it will be always `0`

Answer (score 0):

very simple use of jquery is just like below

```
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function () {
          $("#left_panel").toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
    });
});
</script>
```